# Distributing big data storage for non-relational data

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, non-relational-database

The problem consists of a lot (apprx. 500 million per day)  of non-relational messages of relatively small size (apprx. 1KB). The messages are written once and never modified again. The messages has various structures, though there are patterns that the message must fit in. This data then must be used to make a search over them. The search may be done on any fields of the message, the only always present field is the date, thus the search will be done for a specific day.

The approach I have come up so far is to use MongoDB. Each day I create a few collections (apprx. 2000)  and distribute messages during the day to those collections according to the pattern. I find the patterns important because I make indexing that the number of indexes is limited to 64.

This strategy results in `500G of data + 150G of indexes = 650G` per day. Of course, the question here is how to distribute those data? Obvious solution is to use Mongo Sharding and spread the collections over the shards. However, I have not find any scenario close to my problem described in mongo manuals. Moreover, I am not even sure if I can dynamically (not manually) add new collections every day to shards. Any knowledge/suggestions from expreinced users? Shoudl I change my design?

Comment: May i know the reason behind creating multiple collections(apprx. 2000) daily?

Comment: I end up with 2000 patterns of messages to fit into 64 index limit in mongo. If you merge all of them in one collection you will have to have like thounds of  indexes.

Comment: Every day do you get 2000 new patterns?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry for that. 2000 types of messages. so if everyday I get 500 million of messages, each of them will have a structure (field number and names) that will fit in one of 2000 types.

Comment: So, in that case, the collection creation is an only one-time effort. you don't need create collections dynamically>

Comment: It is one time effort per day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189332/discussion-between-mani-and-yuki).